# How is MJ distributed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

Let's say I am generating 50MJ/t and I connect a quarry (max 55MJ/t) and a Pulverizer (max 4MJ/t).  Will it send the full 4MJ/t to the Pulverizer and the rest to the quarry?  Does it look at the total power demand and provide everything with an equal percentage if its full demand?

How will the MJ be distributed?

Comment: This depends very much on what you are using to connect things. I'm assuming conduits?

Comment: Buildcraft pipes or Thermal Expansion conduits? The distribution logic is in the series of tubes.

Comment: @fredley That only determines how much is actually delivered and can be seen as a simple increase in demand.  A good answer would explain all connection types.

Answer (score 1):

Buildcraft energy is distributed by requests. A machine will request an amount of energy from the network it is attached to, and if there is power to meet or partially meet that demand, it will be delivered, subject to any losses along the way.

The answer to your question is complex, and depends hugely on what machines you have connected, and how they go about requesting energy, and how much they can store.

You can actually work this out for yourself in game using an [MJ Reader](http://mccirclejerks.wikia.com/wiki/MJ_Reader#Average_Distribution) to see how much power is, on average, arriving at certain machines.

However, as you can see from the description of the tool, it is a complex process, requiring averaging measurements out over a period of time. There is no simple answer to this.

Comment: -1 to BC for not having machines request energy consistently :(